# Generating <li> options from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a little bit confused on what my question is, so Im not sure if this is the right question title.

Lets say that I have a table named "teachers", with id(unique) firstname lastname email and phone columns.

I can get the data through a query from this database, but I was wondering, what if I want to include them on a navigation?  How can I create a navigation (list) which will automatically include every unique row?

For example, lets say that I got 3 rows. I want the navigation to have a list with 3 `<li>` options,  and when I click on them I want it to direct to each teacher's unique page. It is kinda hard for me to explain cause I am a bit confused, just have on your mind that I want to have this navigation `<li>` automatically generated, instead of adding `<li>` options manually on the page.

Also if I got like 3 or 4 queries of this type on a page?Is it gonna affect the loading time?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are explaining about "Dynamic Menus". Check this link http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/dynamic-menu-in-php/

Comment: You've tagged this with PHP and MySQL. So you've correctly answered your own question

Comment: If i understand your question well enough, you should do this programmatically, through a loop  for example.If this is what you need, i will post an example for you.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I create a navigation (list) which will automatically include every unique row?

You can query the database. Loop through the results and output an `<li>` with a link for each one. You can write the query in a way that it returns only the unique rows, but to show how to do that you need to post a new question with the table schema, or use your favorite Internet search engine.

> Also if I got like 3 or 4 queries of this type on a page?Is it gonna affect the loading time?

Doing lots of queries, or a few expensive queries, will eventually affect loading time but you don't need to worry about it yet. First learn how to use PHP and MySQL, optimizations come later.